# Update сущность с полем updatable = false

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, spring-data

Использую JPA + Spring Data + Hibernate для записи данных. Есть сервис с вот таким методом (реализация JPA репозитория стандартная):

```
@Transactional
public EmployeeJpaBean create(final EmployeeJpaBean employeeJpaBean) {
    return employeeJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(employeeJpaBean);
}
```

Сущность EmployeeJpaBean имеет такое вот поле:

```
@Column(name = "empl_name", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
private String name;
```

Как видно - оно не должно быть updatable.
Проверяю это в юнит тесте вот так:

```
@Test
public void updateNameTest() {
    EmployeeJpaBean employeeJpaBean = new EmployeeJpaBean();
    employeeJpaBean.setName("old");
    EmployeeJpaBean saved = employeeService.create(employeeJpaBean); //1
    Long id = saved.getId();

    saved.setName("new name");
    saved = employeeService.create(employeeJpaBean); //2
    //падает Assert.assertEquals("old", saved.getName());
    EmployeeJpaBean read = employeeService.read(id); //3
    Assert.assertEquals("old", read.getName());
}
```

На закомментированной строке Assertion падает. Глянул что пишет Hibernate - при выполнении строк кода помеченными 2 и 3 - выполняется один и тот же select, но результат на выходе разный.

1. Во первых, почему разный результат select'ов?
2. а во вторых - как сделать так, чтобы неверные данные не возвращались из метода saveAndFlush ? (ведь поле не updatable).

Comment: Ап !! need help !

Answer (score 1):

В [документации сказано](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#updatable%28%29), что `updatable=false` влияет только на генерацию UPDATE запросов.

В строке (1) мы создаем новую сущность и у нас должен генерироваться `SQL INSERT` запрос.
В строке (2) мы вызываем метод `employeeJpaRepository.saveAndFlush`, который по [документации](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-jpa/1.7.x/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#saveAndFlush-S-) ([исходный код](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java)) должен вызвать `save(entity)` and `flush()`.

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S saveAndFlush(S entity) {
    S result = save(entity);
    flush();

    return result;
}
```

В свою очередь метод `save(entity)` имеет такой вид:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Т.к. объект у нас уже существует, то будет вызван метод `em.merge(entity);`

Идем в описание метода merge. Обращаемся к [JSR-220](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-oth-JSpec/) (вот [ссылка](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_0-fr-spec-persistence.pdf?AuthParam=1501531629_a1278b338ffa49dd2766f4e4ccd669a6) на pdf, но возможно, чтобы открыть надо принять лицензионное соглашение). Идем в секцию:

> 3.2.4.1 Merging Detached Entity State
>   The semantics of the merge operation applied to an entity X are as follows:
>
> - ...
> - ...
> - If X is a managed entity, it is ignored by the merge operation, however, the merge operation is cascaded to entities referenced by relationships from X if these relationships have been anno- tated with the cascade element value cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL annotation.

---

> Более простой вариант из интернета:
>
> - if the entity is already in the persistence context (session), no action is taken, except for cascades

---

> Вольный перевод:
>
> Если Х это managed сущность, то она будет проигнорирована при merge операции, но она будет применена к каскадно связанным сущностям...

Но почему же у нас все-таки идет SELECT в строке (2)? Идет запрос за "самой последней" версией нашей сущности, чтобы потом механизмом [dirty checking](https://letslearnjava.quora.com/Dirty-Checking-in-Hibernate) мы нашли изменения и смогли сгенерировать UPDATE query.

Подытоживая все вышесказанное и отвечая на вопросы:

1. Результат обоих запросов SELECT одинаковый, но просто при merge возвращается уже существующий объект из сессии, в котором уже изменено значение `name`.
2. Сходу могу предложить модифицировать метод таким образом

   ```
    @Transactional
    public EmployeeJpaBean create(final EmployeeJpaBean employeeJpaBean) { 
        employeeJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(employeeJpaBean);

        return employeeService.read(employeeJpaBean.getId());
    }
   ```

Но над вторым ответом на вопрос я еще подумаю...